# How to create a selection based on start and end in Draft.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

I am trying to replace the last insert in Draft.js

For example,

> Orignal string -> aaazzz
>
> After inserting 'bbb' in the middle -> aaabbbzzz
>
> Replace last insert by 'ccc' -> aaaccczzz
>
> Replace last insert by 'ddd' -> aaadddzzz
>
> ...

One way I thought is saving the insert start point. After inserting, save the end point. Then I can replace the range later

This is my inserting code

```
const selection1 = editorState.getSelection();
const contentState1 = editorState.getCurrentContent();

const contentState2 = Modifier.insertText(contentState, selection, text);
const editorState2 = EditorState.push(editorState, newContentState);
const selection2 = newEditorState.getSelection();
// here I don't know how to get the range based on selection1 and selection2
```

I can use

```
const start = selection1.getStartOffset();
const end = selection2.getEndOffset();
```

to get two numbers which are start and end points.

Based on the definition of

```
replaceText(
  contentState: ContentState,
  rangeToReplace: SelectionState,
  text: string,
  inlineStyle?: DraftInlineStyle,
  entityKey?: ?string
): ContentState
```

I need get a new selection. How to create the selection using those two numbers OR selection1 and selection2? Is there any function like

```
createSelection(start, end)  // not exist
```

Answer (score 5):

the doc says:

```
var selectionState = SelectionState.createEmpty('blockkey');
var updatedSelection = selectionState.merge({
  focusOffset: 0,
  anchorOffset:20,
});
```

so you need to get the block key then set offset. the start/end correspond to anchor/focus because in your situation.

Comment: What is a block key and where do you get it?

Comment: https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-content-block/

Comment: Thanks! I think the order is wrong though, it should be `anchorOffset` for the start and `focusOffset` for the end.

Comment: @BertrandBordage that's the same range.

Comment: @Jiang YD Yes, but in the opposite direction, which leads to unwanted behaviour when you use the selection.

Comment: interesting... how replace a range acting different？

Answer (score 1):

I changed my mind. My solution is

1. Save the old `editorState` first.
2. Then insert to the current `editorState`.
3. When I want to insert another one, instead of insert to the current `editorState`, I insert to the copy of the old `editorState` again.

Hopefully, this can give someone who have the same question some ideas.